# does Gatling rampConcurrentUsers translate to requests per second?

Tags: gatling

Does `rampConcurrentUsers` in Gatling translate directly to users per second?

So if my simulation has the following

```
 setUp(
      myscenario.inject(       
        rampConcurrentUsers(concurrentUserMin) to (concurrentUserMax) during (durationInMinutes minutes),
      )
```

can I conclude that on average I have `N= (concurrentUserMax - concurrentUserMin)/2` requests per second? Is that accurate or does it just mean we have N concurrent users on average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rampConcurrentUsers starts users over the duration you specify to gradually increase the number of concurrently active users. How many requests those users generate, and at what rate, depends not just on the number of active users, but also on what requests are in the scenario, how long those requests take to execute, any pauses etc...

So to answer your question... no.